# Scalable Solution using Azure Formrecognizer

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I'm trying to extract table data from pdf files and for that i'm using Azure formrecognizer service.

I created a custom model and trained it (using Neural option).

Then using that trained model now i'm able to get the desired output (write data to csv) from the pdf files.

Query:

- How do i scale this process end-to-end. Currently i'm using databricks notebook and azure formrecognizer sdk package to process the pdf files. Basically calling the rest api end point of trained custom model for each source pdf files.
- With the above setup i can process one file at a time, how can i run the same parallely. There are lots of pdf files that i need to process (around 1k)
- How often i need to train my custom model.

Please let me know what are all scalable options available with azure formrecognizer

Comment: Please let me know if there is any options available

Comment: So if you have pdf files in different structure table format than you have to create separate custom model for each pdf  and then you can compose if all the pdf which you have trained is unique then it works perfect on test data!

Comment: yes i'm using the composite trained model to process pdf files with different pattern. Question is how can i use the same model parallelly for large number of pdf files. I need some scalable options with this custom trained model

Comment: You can try out with azure function which is scalable and you can use blobtrigger to  trigger files from azure blobs and it has the capability to run on threads so processing is much higher